# Unable to render content in Angular template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm implementing ngx-carousel in my application.

When I hard code the data it is working fine. But with server data it is not working.

Below is my code.

```
this.contentfulService.getContent('ourSpecialties')
  .then(ourSpecialties => {
    this.ourSpecialties = ourSpecialties;
    console.log(this.ourSpecialties);
  });
```

HTML

```
  <owl-carousel-o *ngIf="ourSpecialties" [options]="customOptions">
    <ng-template *ngFor="let ourSpecialtie of ourSpecialties" carouselSlide>
      <img src="{{ourSpecialtie.fields.image.fields.file.url}}">
      <h3>{{ourSpecialtie.fields.title}}</h3>
      <p>{{ourSpecialtie.fields.description}}</p>
    </ng-template>

  </owl-carousel-o>
```

I can see the data in console for `ourSpecialties`.

Let me know what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please add this behind/after the carousel:   <pre>{{ ourSpecialties | json }}</pre>. Do you see it in the browser?

Comment: I see the data in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*ngFor` directive microsyntax is expanded into an outer `<ng-template>` tag. Probably the inner template isn't rendered. Try to wrap the `*ngFor` in a `<ng-container>` tag. Try the following

```js
<owl-carousel-o *ngIf="ourSpecialties" [options]="customOptions">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let ourSpecialtie of ourSpecialties">
    <ng-template carouselSlide>
      <img src="{{ourSpecialtie.fields.image.fields.file.url}}">
      <h3>{{ourSpecialtie.fields.title}}</h3>
      <p>{{ourSpecialtie.fields.description}}</p>
    <ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</owl-carousel-o>
```

Comment: I've edited the code, please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you are receiving from the server may be different. Are you receiving an array or an Iterable?